# convergence of the series $\sum u_n, u_n = \frac{n^n x^n}{n!}$ for $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While checking the convergence of the series $\sum u_n, u_n = \frac{n^n x^n}{n!}$ for $x>0$, we used ratio test to say that for $0< x < \frac1e$ $\sum u_n$ is convergent and for $\frac1e < x<\infty$ $\sum u_n$ is divergent.

We use Logarithimic Test for the case $x = \frac1e$, where we came across computing the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n+n^2 \log \frac{n}{n+1}$$ but I am stuck in finding the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
n+n^2\log\frac{n}{n+1} = n-n^2\log\frac{n+1}{n} = n-n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
So do some asymptotics.  As $n \to +\infty$, we have
\begin{align}
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) &= \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\\
n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) &= n-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)
\\
n-n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) &= \frac{1}{2}+o(1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It follows from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) that$$\frac{n^n\left(\frac1e\right)^n}{n!}=\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}\geqslant\sqrt{2\pi n}.$$Therefore, the series diverges.