# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \frac{(n^n)(x^n)}{(n!)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

With the help of ratio test, I have been successful in proving it is convergent for
$ex<1$ and divergent for $ex>1$. however for $ex=1$, the ratio test has failed. Hence I had to apply the logarithm test.

The form after applying log test is: n*(-n*log(1+1/n)+1)
this is where it's becoming problematic for me. I do not have any idea how to proceed from here. any help is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: So which one grows faster, $n^n$ or $n!$?

Comment: n! will grow faster i suppose.

Comment: This question was shown among related questions in the sidebar: [convergence of the series $\sum u_n, u_n = \frac{n^n x^n}{n!}$ for $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944305). Perhaps you might find some other posts about the same series [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5En%20x%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}=(1+\frac1 n)^{n} x$ so the ratio test tells you that the series converges for $|x| <\frac 1 e$ and diverges for $|x|>\frac  1 e$. 
When $x =\frac 1 e$ use Stirling's formula to compare the series with $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ to see that the series diverges.

Comment: yes, i actually got that result, but its said that i also have to find the state of the series if x=1/e, and hence  requesting a help with the logarithm test.

Comment: i very much appreciate your answer, thank you.

Comment: Instead of using logarithms you can use stirling's formula for $x =\frac 1 e$.